# select a column with the highest id which have common fields

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

i have a table named iview:

```
gpreq_id    a_id   m_id     rcv_qty
1           100      4         0
2           100      4         1
3           100      5         4
4           101      4         1
5           101      4         10
6           101      4         1
```

how can i select this that the m_id in the a_id's has the highest gpreq_id?

like:

```
gpreq_id    a_id   m_id     rcv_qty
2           100      4         1
3           100      5         4
6           101      4         1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
SELECT i1.*
FROM iview as i1
WHERE i1.gpreq_id IN (SELECT MAX(gpreq_id) 
                     FROM iview as i2 
                     GROUP BY i2.a_id, i2.m_id)
```

Here is the **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/c2ad4/3)**

Answer (score 1):

First find max value for each `a_id, m_id` pair and then join to iview:

```
select i.* 
 from iview as i 
  inner join (
  select a_id, m_id, max(gpreq_id) as max_gpreq_id
   from iview 
  group by a_id, m_id
) as mi on (mi.max_gpreq_id = i.pgreq_ie)
```